# Mysql how to add if else in order by clause to order based on same column but opposite order

Tags: mysql

I want to conditionally order my SQL query in an ascending or descending order based on fixed column "LogDateTime". Whether we need to order asc/desc is based on the input parameter "v_isasc". This is the query I have written so far:

```
 select * from logs
 order by (case WHEN v_isasc = 1 THEN LogDateTime END) ASC,
          (case WHEN v_isasc <> 1 THEN LogDateTime END) DESC;
```

Can we do this by a simpler query OR using if/else?